# Angularjs ng-repeat remove selected option from multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using ng-repeat am loading multiple select dropdown elements and each dropdown has the same set of values loaded.
Once the user selects an option from the select box; The selected option shouldn't appear in other select boxes(options).

Example: If the user selects Option A from select: 1; then in select: 2 or any other select: N the Option A shouldn't appear and vice-versa.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/yCFIanCXPece49dk?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview

Code:

```
 <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions | filter:arrayFilter(select.selectedOption,$index)" value="{{option.id}}">

   $scope.arrayFilter = function(selectionArray, position) {
    return function(item, index) {
      return selectionArray.indexOf(item.id) == -1 || item.id == selectionArray[position];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the options to the nested ng-repeat with a function, and then filter out options which are not the current one and are selected:

html:

```
<select name="repeatSelect{{$index}}" id="repeatSelect{{$index}}" ng-model="select.selectedOption">
  <option
    ng-repeat="option in getAvailableOptions(select.selectedOption)"
    value="{{option.id}}"
  >
    {{option.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

controller:

```
$scope.getAvailableOptions = function(current) {
  return this.data.availableOptions.filter((o) => o.id === current || !this.data.availableSelect.some(s => s.selectedOption === o.id));
};
```

and here is a forked [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/G6W5dYY2qOepKW5b?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

Comment: Forked the plunker to include the empty select; If the user wants to reuse/reset to option value. 

https://plnkr.co/edit/uhPuqkD1bd1hqrbf?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1